# How to properly save gedit java_home file

Tags: java, directory, gedit, environment-variables, file-association

Every tutorial I've read about setting java_home environment variable via gedit just says "save and exit" save to where?

Can I save this particular gedit file as such **/home/nexogen/developer/gedit_java**

Or must I save this gedit file to **/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle**

*as in save the gedit file which contains the java_home environment variable command in the same directory as jave_home itself*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have understand your problem. You're opening /etc/environment file as normal user and then cannot save the file at that place.

You won't open it as normal user. Instead you'll open as root user. To do so, First open a terminal by pressing `Ctrl-Alt-T` keyboard shortcut.

Then write this command there to open as root

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/environment
```

This will open the file as root.

`JAVA_HOME` is an environment variable. It is set to a directory containing JDK installation like this line

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I assumed jdk is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle folder.

You'll add this line at the end of that file and save by pressing `Ctrl-S`. This will overwrite the file at place. ***You don't need to save this file anywhere else as you opened this as root***

Now exit gedit.

Logout and login again to see the effect of setting JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Yes I know what gedit is and I also know the proper directory. I opened gedit and opened /etc/environment and then ran command "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle" now I'm frustrated because It's not just save and exit... When I run the command and go to save, I must choose a directory to save to. The home directory initially pops up. I simply need to know where I should save to (the location I should save the gedit untitled document to) using the GUI I went into the directory /usr/lib/jvm and Java-8-oracle is there. But java-8-oracle is also still located in /etc/environment

Comment: you will save it in. bashrc file. /etc/environment is for system usage. Use the file in your home not /etc/environment.

Comment: When you say write a line at the end of .bashrc what do you mean? I am ready to save and I selected .bashrc I was going to save as "JAVA_HOME.bashrc in the home directory... Is this not proper?

Comment: No. It's not. You'll open. bashrc first. add lines on that file and save that file

Comment: @nexogen.io I think I understood your problem and updated the answer. Check it.your problem was you weren't opening the file as root

Answer (score 1):

Well I recommend you to add the following in the file  /etc/profile so that the java path could be usable system-wide. JAVA_HOME and PATH variable can be set as follows : *Open up a terminal*

> sudo nano /etc/profile

At the following statements at the bottom of the file , I am assuming your java extracted folder is at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Save the file by pressing **Ctrl + x   y  *enter***

Better give read and execute permission for the Java installation folder as follows :

```
sudo chmod -R a+rx /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I also recommend to update alternative for all the application to use java when required as follows :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javaws
```

Now reload the profile file we have updated as follows in the terminal.
*Note: There is a space between **.** and **/etc/profile** in the below command.*

```
. /etc/profile
```

That's it